# Why Dispatching Event.OPEN Instead of IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR?

Tags: actionscript-3, error-handling, webserver, dispatcher

Why does the `load` method of the `URLStream` class dispatch `Event.OPEN` instead of `IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR` when the SWF is on a webserver and when trying to load an invalid URL?

The same doesn't apply when running the SWF locally.

Sample code:

```
var CLS_UrlStream:URLStream = new URLStream(); // Initialize URLStream class instance.
CLS_UrlStream.addEventListener(Event.OPEN, FUN_StreamHandler); // Listen for successful connections.
CLS_UrlStream.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, FUN_StreamHandler); // Listen for conenction errors.
CLS_UrlStream.load(new URLRequest("InvalidURL")); // Load file.

private function FUN_StreamHandler(FUN_PAR_Event:Event):void {
trace("EVENT TYPE: " + FUN_PAR_Event.type);
}
// Outputs: EVENT TYPE: open
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the SWF is running on the server and is requesting for a resource that doesn't exist, the server actually sends an error message which counts as data, thus there is no error event. The same didn't apply locally because there was no web server to respond with an error when a request for an nonexistent file is made. Discovered this by tracing live with the Monster Debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Event.OPEN gets triggered on load. So will always be called.

You probably want HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS

Comment: I'm keeping HTTP_STATUS as an alternative, but regarding Event.OPEN - it always gets triggered when the executed SWF is accessed from a webserver, but not when executed locally. I would like to understand why is that. Why is the event dispatched differently even if it is listened to in the same manner?

Comment: Okay, I got it: When the SWF is running on the server and is requesting for a resource that doesn't exist, the server actually sends an error message which counts as data, thus there is no error event. The same didn't apply locally because there was no web server to respond with an error when a request for an nonexistent file is made. Discovered this by tracing live with the Monster Debugger.

Comment: Basically, its the difference between streaming and normal loading.

Comment: You mean URLLoader? I didn't mention in my post, but I needed to use URLStream to close the stream as soon as a resource was opened. I tried URLLoader, but it was giving me an error telling me that there's was no stream initiated.

Comment: URLLoader has issues with the close function it does not do anything. URLStream has a working close fucntion. I went through that same issue.

Comment: look into a question I posted here I ran across an issue with using URLStream to load images. There is a link to the original class I found.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498419/streamed-png-using-urlstream-intermittent-when-server-is-bogged